# How to search a string for multiple multi-word phrases in Swift or Objective-C

Tags: ios, arrays, objective-c, swift, strpos

I want to parse a large number of strings for canned phrases or names and then store the names, if found, in an array where the order counts.

So for example, starting with a string such as:

```
str = "The movie stars Robert Duvall and James Earl Jones and pits them against a villain played expertly by Brando in an action packed adventure."
```

I would like to search against an array of actors:

`names = [Robert Duvall, Henry Fonda, Brando, Marlon Brando, Jane Fonda, James Earl Jones, Peter Fonda, Montgomery Clift]` etc where the actors can have one, two or three names.

Initially, I could simply check for a match on the triples using `strpos` or convert the string to triples and do a match on triples as in James Earl Jones. Then I could remove his name and search the remainders for other doubles or individual words. However, this approach starts to get very complicated quickly and I'm wondering if there isn't a more elegant approach.

//This road looks very messy indeed...

```
NSArray *triples = [self getTriples:str];//get all combinations of three sequential words
NSArray *pieces = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray * matches = [NSMutableArray new];
for (long i = 0;i<[triples count];i++) {
   NSString *phrase = triples[i];
   for (long j = 0;j<[names count];j++) {
      NSString *name = names[j];
      if ([phrase caseInsensitiveCompare:name]==NSOrderedSame) {
         [matches addObject:phrase];
         //Rumps has two elements, before and after
         rumps = [str componentsSeparatedByString:phrase];
         NSString *start = rumps[0];
         NSString *end = rumps[1];
         //Search before for a name
         //search after for a name
      }
   }
}//end triples
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What is your expected result for a string "Marlon Brando and Brando saw Brando and Marlon Brando"?

Comment: Have a look at the Natural Language framework, it will do a lot of work for you in this domain. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/naturallanguage/identifying_people_places_and_organizations

Comment: @pawello, the expected result would be [Marlon Brando], eg an array containing one actor so there should be prevention of dupes.

Comment: So [Marlon Brando] and [Brando] are two differenct arrays?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to search the string and pull out the actors mentioned in order to get an array of actors in order of appearance.  If one actor is mentioned twice eg as marlon brando and then brando, then after the mapping to the actor, I can remove the dupes easily enough using something like [[NSSet setWithArray:yourarray] allObjects]; However, I'm struggling with comparing the string to the various possible actor names that might be used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea based on your `names` string.

1. Split `names` on comma and and store in array say `a1`
2. Loop through `a1` and see if you have any match on full name
3. If not, loop `a1` again and split on spaces into `a2`

Here I am not that clear on your logic, but maybe like so? Now in this inner loop, where you loop `a2`

4. If `a2` has three elements / names then you assume no match? Or you can check all possible combinations, not too bad for just 3 (123 already checked, then 132, 213, 231, 312, 321 and you're done with 3 names).
5. If it has two elements only check in reverse (21, you already checked 12).
6. If still no match you can check on the individual elements of `a2` if that is what you want, so check on 1, 2 (and possibly 3).

Any match you use the corresponding `a1` element - which is what you want, the full name, right?

You can use an index set and set the index into `a1` - the actor you found to prevent dups.

Comment: Based on your answer, and that of @CRD it sounds like there is no magic trick and I'll have to work it out step by step. Will give this a try

Comment: Exactly! No short cuts, but you can still do it smartly. Everywhere you check for an actor's name in a string and if found you want to remove the name from the string to avoid dups, so make that a separate function for starters. You call that function in 2, 4, 5 and 6. Also maybe create a function for 4 to check the string with an array of three names and three indices then you can just call that, e.g. ```check3:( NSString * ) sentence names3:( NSArray< NSString * > * ) names3 i1:( int ) i1 i2:( int ) i2 i3:( int ) i3```. Heck you can pass ```NSNotFound``` for ```i3``` and also use this in 6.

Comment: The formatting is messing it up, but you will call that as follows ```[check3:s names3:n i1:0 i2:2 i3:1]``` to e.g. check for 132 and so on. Then it will be nice and concise and modular and you will get a warm feeling when it runs - or so I've heard.

Comment: ... oops ... I meant you can use ```NSNotFound``` and also check in **5** previously ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible algorithm *sketch*, there will be no real code – indeed as I write this it has not been written in Objective-C or Swift, it is an *algorithm* which can be implemented in both (and other) languages.

In coding it you may find the algorithm missed something (i.e. there could be errors, this was written directly into the answer, it is a *sketch*!), in which case go back and refine the algorithm and repeat.

Our sample name list:

> James Earl Jones, James, Marlon Brando, Earl Jones, Brando, James Earl

and sample text:

> James, James Earl and James Earl Jones all regular meet for coffee

The algorithm is based around the observations:

*[Note: In the description we assume left-to-right text and that search for a match moves left-to right. The algorithm will work for right-to-left with simple adjustments, for mixed direction text it will get messier!]*

1. Matches cannot overlap. E.g. "James Earl" is not both "James" *and* "James Earl". We say a match consumes the test.
2. Only names which are *prefixes* of another one need care, ones which are *postfixes" do not. E.g. If looking for "James" and "James Earl" you must look for the latter first to avoid getting a match on "James" and then missing "James Earl" as a match on "James" has consumed those characters. However "Earl Jones" and "James Earl Jones" can be searched for at the same time, the latter will match first.
3. In a collection of names which do not contain any prefixes they can all be matched at the same time using a regular expression with alternates. E.g. "James Earl Jones" and "Earl Jones" can be matched by the RE "James Earl Jones|Earl Jones"
4. When you have prefixes, so you search for the longer first, a match for a shorter name can only occur to the left of the match for the longer one.

The algorithm uses regular expression matching, as provided by `NSRegularExpression` in Objective-C & Swift; and ranges, as provided by `NSRange`, which allow searching in part of a string.

The outline:

1. Sort you names. E.g.:

> Brando, Earl Jones, James, James Earl, James Earl Jones, Marlon Brando

2. Divide your names into two lists by removing any name which is a prefix of its *immediately following* name and placing into a second list. E.g.

> Brando, Earl Jones, James Earl Jones, Marlon Brando
> James, James Earl

3. If the second list is not empty repeat step (2) producing a third list, keep repeating until no prefixes have been removed. E.g. our sample names produce the 3 lists:

> Brando, Earl Jones, James Earl Jones, Marlon Brando
> James Earl
> James

4. Convert each list to a regular expression using alternation to produce a list of regular expressions to use in searching. E.g.:

> "Brando|Earl Jones|James Earl Jones|Marlon Brando", "James Earl", "James"

*(At this point we realise the sample names could have been better as only the first RE required alternation. Oh well...)*

Now we are ready to use our prepared regular expressions to find the matches.

5. Set the *search range* to the whole text, the *match range* to be empty/no value.
6. Set the *current RE* to the first
7. Using the current RE do a search for the first match within the *search range* to produce a *match range*. If there is no new match goto (9). E.g. using our sample, where the match range is indicated by []'s:

> James, James Earl and [James Earl Jones] all regular meet for coffee

8. Set the new search range to be from the start of the current search range to the end of the match range, advance the current RE, goto (6). E.g. the sequence of matches for the first name goes:

> James, James Earl and [James Earl Jones] all regular meet for coffee
> James, [James Earl] and James Earl Jones
> [James], James Earl

9. We now have our first matching range, record it, set the new search range to be from the end of the matched range to the end of the text, and if this new search range is non-empty goto 6.
10. Done, we have the list of matches.

If you don't want the list of actual matches but just a collection of unique matches then accumulate a set (e.g. `NSMutableSet`/`Set`) of matches as you go.

Have fun coding (and refining, coding...) the algorithm. If you get stuck ask a new question, reference this Q&A, describe your algorithm as it is then, show your implementation, detailed your problem, etc. and someone will undoubtedly help you along. HTH.

Comment: Thank you I'll try to implement this!